# jQuery Show/Hide Div

Tags: jquery

I'm using this for a show/hide div expander, which is working fine, however, the HTML entities aren't being outputted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slickbox').hide();
    $("#slick-toggle").toggle(function() {
        $(this).text("&#9650; See Less");
        $('.slickbox').slideToggle(500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).text("See More &#9660;");
        $('.slickbox').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Instead of showing the up or down arrow entities, it just outputs

```
&#9660;
```

How can I make it so it'll output the entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.text` already does the conversion from "text" to "HTML" itself.

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2):

> We need to be aware that this method
>   escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render
>   correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method .createTextNode(),
>   which replaces special characters with
>   their HTML entity equivalents (such as
>   < for <).

So your text is being converted to `&amp;#9650;` and thus being rendered, from your point-of-view, *verbatim*.

You can encode the literal directly into the string (noting that the Javascript `\u` expects Hex, not Decimal):

```
$(this).text("\u25B2 See Less");
```

If you want to use the HTML entities:

```
$(this).html("&#9650; See Less");
```

See [this jsfiddle.net snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/g9CS5/) that shows:

- Your approach
- A valid approach with encoding the literal directly into the Javascript string
- The approach with `.html`.

Comment: Thank you for your well written answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .html rather then .text

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slickbox').hide();
    $("#slick-toggle").toggle(function() {
        $(this).html("&#9650; See Less");
        $('.slickbox').slideToggle(500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).html("See More &#9660;");
        $('.slickbox').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

.text() doesn't process any html entity. You must use .html() in this case.

Comment: This is backwards. `.text()` _DOES_ process entities, so the ampersand `&` is being encoded to make it HTML-compatible. `html()` already expects HTML-compatible entities, so no translation takes place.

Comment: Sorry, did you test it? I had the same problem time ago and I fixed it using .html(). Anyway, I will take a look to documentation.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct solution; it's your explanation that's not correct.